# Ideal examples of Magnoliophyta Lilianae

Tags: flowers

What are the ideal examples of Magnoliophyta (Lilianae-to be precise) for a teacher to show students? 
And, does anybody know exact name of this flower? [Picture](https://scontent.fzag3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/fr/cp0/e15/q65/59640734_2217225111703760_920197091060350976_o.jpg?_nc_cat=104&efg=eyJpIjoidCJ9&_nc_ht=scontent.fzag3-1.fna&oh=0a0cb0e3fc36f487449560c64721b7e5&oe=5D72C476)